# ffmpeg comand equivalent to MediaCoder option

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

i used to use [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) to convert mp3 files to aac. Using [this](https://yadi.sk/i/S4Zw3XXJ3P6RYj) option. Now i have access to linux and i would like to know how to do it with ffmpeg command, if posible...

As far as i get it, the closest one should be:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 48k file.aac
```

isn't?

Regards,

Comment: That mediacoder is using HE_AAC profile which the native encoder doesn't support. You'll need a build with `libfdk_aac` linked in.

Comment: I see. After i've done done, do i have to change `-c:a aac` for `-c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg does not support the 3GPP HE-AAC encoder that you have been using.

If you want HE-AAC support, you need an ffmpeg build that has `libfdk_aac`, since the default `aac` encoder only supports AAC-LC. The [Compilation Guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/) explain how to achieve that; [static builds](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) of ffmpeg do not have `libfdk_aac` for licensing reasons.

The equivalent command is:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 48k output.aac
```